# .NET Generics: Is it possible to enforce abstract class on generic type

Tags: .net, generics

I have the following code:

```
void DoSomething<T>() where T : class
{
    if(typeof(T).IsAbstract)
         // do something with T
    else
         // throw an error
}
```

Is it possible to enforce that T is an abstract class in the generic's definition (something like `where T : abstract class`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. cf §10.1.5 of the C# specification. In particular, the grammar makes it very clear that this is not possible.

```
type-parameter-constraints-clauses:
    type-parameter-constraints-clause
    type-parameter-constraints-clauses   type-parameter-constraints-clause
type-parameter-constraints-clause:
    where   type-parameter   :   type-parameter-constraints
type-parameter-constraints:
    primary-constraint
    secondary-constraints
    constructor-constraint
    primary-constraint   ,   secondary-constraints
    primary-constraint   ,   constructor-constraint
    secondary-constraints   ,   constructor-constraint
    primary-constraint   ,   secondary-constraints   ,   constructor-constraint
primary-constraint:
    class-type
    class
    struct
secondary-constraints:
    interface-type
    type-parameter
    secondary-constraints   ,   interface-type
    secondary-constraints   ,   type-parameter
constructor-constraint
    new   (   )
```

You can have a guard clause in the method body:

```
Contract.Requires<InvalidOperationException>(!typeof(T).IsAbstract);
```

Comment: Thanks that helps!   Is there a reason that this is not supported in the grammar?

Answer (score 0):

A generic type declaration generates a run-time type  per T argument created from the generic type (I think) upon first instantiation. Since an abstract class by definition cannot be instantiated, these two principles directly contradict.